# How to check that a string is equal to one of two strings in Python

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
print("What is your Name")
user_name = input("User Name: ")
print(f"Hello {user_name} please choose a dish and a drink from this menu : \n Fish \t Eggs \n Water \t Juice")
food = input("Please input your desired dish: ")
drink = input("Please input your desired drink: ")
if food != "Fish" or "Eggs":
  print("Please input a correct dish or drink")
else:
  print(f"{user_name} your desired drink is {drink} and your desired dish is {food}")
```

The main problem is the final part. I'm trying to say "if food is not equal to Fish or Eggs print the error message but if it is print the success message". But, if you copy the code and follow it at the end it always prints the error message.

Answer (score 4):

### Code:

```
print("What is your Name")
user_name = input("User Name: ")
print(f"Hello {user_name} please choose a dish and a drink from this menu : \n Fish \t Eggs \n Water \t Juice")
food = input("Please input your desired dish: ")
drink = input("Please input your desired drink: ")
if food not in ("Fish","Eggs"):
  print("Please input a correct dish or drink")
else:
  print(f"{user_name} your desired drink is {drink} and your desired dish is {food}")
```

- You must either write `if food !="Fish" and food !="Eggs":` or `if food not in ("Fish","Eggs"):`

Answer (score 2):

You could do `if food not in ["Fish", "Eggs"]`.

The problem is, you are evaluating `food != "Fish"` and `"Eggs"`. The latter evaluates to `True` in a boolean context. Therefore, the whole statement is evaluated to `True`.

Answer (score -2):

```
if food != "Fish" or "Eggs":
```

your input will always make one of the above condition true, because you have option to input either Fish or Eggs, so instead of `or` you need to use `and` condition with explicit check for both items to satisfy your condition.

```
if food != "Fish" and food != "Eggs":
```